# Follow or nofollow link from translation to the original on another site?

Tags: blog, nofollow, translation, dofollow

When we translate a blog post from a good resource and insert link to the original in our translation, is it better to be follow or nofollow link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a link to a valuable resource like an article/product/category/home page etc, use follow.

No follow is used when you have a lot of unsupervised/user generated content that you do not *necessarily* endorse or generally links that you *do not* endorse through your site.

Basically if the resource is as you state "good", use follow.